# Using coffeescript with nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, forever, nodemon

Currently i discover that i can use `nodemon` with `coffeescript`, without needing to generate the .JS files, searching about i discovery that forever can do the same.

I wonder if use in production will lead to performace issues. I do not think so, since the `Nodemon` and `Forever` generate the javascript files in the dark just one time, when the server starts, then is not needed to generate these javascript files to each user request, correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, but in a production environment you would not use nodemon because your source code (for your currently deployed version) is not supposed to change. Forever would be more appropriate in this game.

Comment: Yeap, i already use forever in my production, that's why i'm so interest  hahahhaa